# Gedit in ubuntu 14.04 does not change theme as normal user

Tags: 14.04, themes, gedit

I am trying to change the theme of gedit from Edit -> Preferences -> Fonts & Colors. But the theme does not get applied. Its the same for built-in themes and any new theme I add.

Screenshot : not applying theme as normal user:

[image]

When run it as gksudo gedit , it is applying the themes.

Screenshot: applied when run as sudo:

[image]

Following is my system setup:

Ubuntu 14.04

Gedit 3.10.4